# Webdriver unable to find element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I was unable to find the element (with id below) with Selenium even though it's visible in the html source page after successfully clicking on 'Search' button (using Selenium) of the previous page that has url as follows:

```java
String url="https://sjobs.brassring.com/1033/ASP/TG/cim_advsearch.asp?partnerid=25314&siteid=5290";
driver.get(url);
if(driver.findElements(By.id("submit1")).size() != 0)
    driver.findElement(By.id("submit1")).click(); // clicking on 'Search' button
if(driver.findElements(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_GridFormatter_YUIGrid")).size() != 0)      
    System.out.println("FOUND!");

String pageSource= driver.getPageSource();
```

"FOUND!" was never rendered, nor pageSource contained the element with the above id. I am using Selenium 2.3.3 and testing with latest versions of IE, Chrome, and Firefox webdrivers. Could someone please help? Thank you.

About 1/3 from the bottom of the target page are the followings (third line is location of the id):

```html
<div id="ctl00_MainContent_GridFormatter_datatable" class="datatable">
<div id="THeadersDiv" style="display:none;">
<table id="ctl00_MainContent_GridFormatter_YUIGrid" class="basicGrid" border="0"> <!-- this is the element in question -->
```

Comment: I tried to open the given page and there is no element with the given ID. You should fix the `By` clause.

Comment: You have to click on 'Search' button at the bottom of the page (left of 'Clear' button) to arrive at the page in discussion with <table id="ctl00_MainContent_GridFormatter_YUIGrid" ...>. I just edited with addition of clicking on 'Search' button programmatically to make things clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.  I believe that the driver cannot find the element because there are two elements both with identical IDs. (which is terrible web code).  I looked at the rest of the code, and it looks like the two elements also share the same class, and are the only two elements with that class.

Therefore, I believe that doing a `By.className(".basicGrid") should work`

Comment: If there are two elements with same id, shouldn't `driver.findElements(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_GridFormatter_YUIGrid")).size()` still get two? `FOUND` should still be printed in this case.

Comment: That's what I thought, but because ID's are supposed to be unique, it may be causing something odd...aka, not finding any of them.

Comment: Wait, I did a search on the page for id (ctl00_MainContent_GridFormatter_YUIGrid) and only 1 turned up. Are you sure you got 2 elements with this same id?

Comment: Hm...You are right.  I went back to the original, and researched, and it worked fine.  I would still recommend trying it by className though.

Comment: So are you saying that "FOUND!" was rendered on your run? Thanks.

Comment: No, I haven't run the automation myself.  When I go to the page myself, I can't find anything with that ID.  I can only find it in the source you posted.  I have no idea what is happening, which is why I'm just throwing out things to try (trying to select it by className)